# Why does this code not do cube roots of negative numbers?

Tags: c, root, cube

I was writing a function in C used to make roots of numbers, and I stumbled upon a problem: it works really well with cube roots of positive numbers and square roots, but when I try to make a cube root of a negative numer, it returns: -1.#IND00 
I tried researching and it turns out the returned number is too big, but I can't understand why...
('rooter' is the function, x is the radicand and ind is the degree.)

I also tried to put in '0.66' instead of 1/ind but the same result happens.

```
float rooter(int x, int ind)
{
    if(ind%2==0)
    {
        if (x>=0)
            return ( pow(x, 1.0/ind) );
        else
            errore=1;
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return ( pow(x, (float)1.0/ind) );
    }
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/cbrt

Comment: For odd roots, you could `return x < 0 ? -pow(-x, (float)1.0/ind) : pow(x, (float)1.0/ind);`.

Comment: Aside: the `(float)` cast serves no useful purpose here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pow](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) does not accept negative base for non integer exponent. (Probably because making the special cases where it is traditionally defined work is too burdensome especially when it is expected to be implemented using logarithms.)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a little more philosophical than the other answers so far and attempts to address the underlying question *"why doesn't pow allow a negative base with a float exponent?"*.

Consider how floating point numbers work and how powers to rational numbers are defined. Now given a negative base, ask yourself for what rational exponents is the result a real number?

Using the usual mathematical definition (-2)^(1/2) isn't a real number but you could find something arbitrarily close to 1/2 for which it is. For example (-2)^(49999/99999) is real. What this means is that if the implementation tried to determine what is and isn't real then any floating point precision error may actually swap your expression from real to imaginary, or vice versa, which would be unstable from a programmers perspective.

Another issue with this type of definition is that it requires us to represent the rational exponent in its most reduced form to determine if the expression is real or not. This isn't generally a trivial representation to determine. Note that (-2)^(2/4) is imaginary, even though the fourth root of -2 squared is real.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by **AProgrammer**, the `pow` function does not accept negative `x` in your circumstances. To get round this, you can 'remember' the sign of `x`, pass its *positive* value (magnitude) to `pow`, then re-apply the sign (as you've already checked that `ind` is an odd number in this case):

```c
else {
    float sign = x < 0.0 ? -1.0 : +1.0;
//  return sign * ( pow(fabs(x), (float)1.0/ind) ); // MNC - see comments
    return sign * ( pow(fabs(x), 1.0/ind) );        // BPC - maybe?
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: @chux In this case, I was using the `MRC` philosophy (Minimum Required Change) (to OP's code) rather than the `BPC` philosophy (Best Possible Code)!  But you make a good point.

Answer (score 0):

pow would have to return complex numbers in order to handle negative bases without a much more complex API. Their approach is fast, easy to use and accessible. There is but one simple rule: the base must be zero or positive ^^

Plus, why the cast to float?

Simply change the code to

```
else
{
    return pow(fabs(x), 1.0 / ind) * (x < 0 ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Comment: I think you need `fabs(x)` as your 1st arg. to `pow`. Also, is `sign(x)` standard C?